# Error '400' on Excel VBA - PDF Print

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am receiving an Error '400' message box - (no other info/text displays), whilst trying to run the following code as per below. I am not overly experienced in VBA and have copied this code from another workbook and adjusted accordingly. In short, the code looks at a drop down list/pivot table filter and will create, name and save a PDF in a specified folder location. Any help would be appreciated! & thank you in advance! :) Below is the following code I am using:

Sub PDFReports()

```
Dim Dropdown1 As String
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim option1 As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim cellcontents As String
Dim SaveAsStr As String

counter = 1
Dropdown1 = "j3"

Set Range1 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown1).Validation.Formula1)

For Each option1 In Range1
ActiveSheet.Range("j3").Select
  ActiveCell.Value = option1.Value 'change dropdown value
   SaveAsStr = "Y:\002 Data Program Documents\001 Practice Data Reports" & _
   ActiveSheet.Range("J3").Value 'save pdf with value in dropdown in filename
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
       SaveAsStr & " Data Report " & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".pdf"
    counter = counter + 1
Next option1

    MsgBox "Reports complete"
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you missing a backslash in your file path after `001 Practice Data Reports`  ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I updated with a backslash, however, it still produces the '400' error

Comment: You have checked that the folder 
Y:\002 Data Program Documents\001 Practice Data Reports
Actually exists?

Comment: What is the full path generated?

Comment: Hi, the folder definitely exists, however, to simplify, I created a folder on my desktop to save the PDF's into but still no luck, the '400' error is still displaying

Comment: What's in `J3` ?

Comment: Hi, J3 has a drop down list / filter which is part of a pivot table. I need the code to filter each item in the drop down list and save a PDF for each filter selection.

Comment: I think it may not be working as the VBA says to look at a dropdown/data validation list. I need for it to look/loop through a Pivot Table filter/drop down... Could anyone assist with updating the code to do this.... Rather than 'Dropdown' it should relate to the Pivot Table